# Linear Search function compiles but no output

Tags: c, algorithm, search, linear-search

I do not understand what is wrong with this code of Linear search. It compiles but on execution exits without output.

```
turns - no. of test cases.
size  - size of array.
x     - element to be searched.


#include <stdio.h>

int linearSearch(int arr[], int size, int element)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == element)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int turns, size;
    scanf("%d", &turns);

    while(turns--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &size);
        int arr[size];

        for(int j=0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", arr[j]);
        }
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        int k = linearSearch(arr, size, x);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't produce any output because there aren't any output statements in the program. Did you forget a call to `puts` or `printf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one major problem in your code.

First you need to pass address of your array element(`&arr[j]`).

And the output is not displaying because you are not printing it out.

The correct code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int linearSearch(int arr[], int size, int element)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == element)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int turns, size;
    scanf("%d", &turns);

    while(turns--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &size);
        int arr[size];

        for(int j=0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
        }
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        int k = linearSearch(arr, size, x);
        printf("%d\n", k);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, It was a silly mistake, I looked at the code so many times but wasn't able to figure out.

Comment: No problem, after some time you can easily figure out such small issues. :)